# Joomla! 2.5.19 external user login

Tags: php, joomla

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a topic related to this Joomla! version. After trying a couple of codes, I decided to open a new topic to ask you experts here. :)

We're using a script with a basic authentication check. After we updated to Joomla! 2.5.19, the old md5 method no longer works. The PHP script is the following:

```
session_start();
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("sql1",$db);

//Joomla user and pass check start
$sql = "SELECT * FROM j25_users WHERE username='".$_POST['user']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db); 
$userdata = mysql_fetch_array($result);
list ($md5pass, $saltpass) = split (":", $userdata['password']);

$POSTPW = crypt ( 'xxgu952rjyiL', 'Xh2loHgxxi5ijuNbGI' );


echo "<br><br>";

$joomlapw=$userdata[password];

echo "POST PW= $POSTPW
<br>
Joomla - PW = $joomlapw
<br>
salt = $saltpass

<br>
";

if(((md5($_POST['pa'].$saltpass))==$md5pass) and ($userdata['usertype']=="Super Administrator" or $userdata['usertype']=="Editor"))
{
echo "success!";
  $jommlapruefung="success";
}

echo "<br>$_POST[user] und $_POST[pa]";



//Joomla user and pass check complete

$dom        =str_replace("lager.","",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);


$_GET['getdir']=str_replace(chr(92),"",$_GET['getdir']);
$_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); 
$_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']); $_GET['getdir']=str_replace("//","/",$_GET['getdir']);
$_GET['getdir']=str_replace(".","_",$_GET['getdir']);

if ($_GET['getdir']==NULL) $_GET['getdir']="/";

if  ( ($_GET['getdir']=="") || ($_GET['getdir']=="/") )
 {
 if ($jommlapruefung!="success" & $_SESSION['best']!='gogo') 
  {
  die("<FORM ACTION=index.php METHOD=POST>
        Username:&nbsp; <INPUT TYPE=text NAME=user LENGTH=25 SIZE=25>
        Password:&nbsp; <INPUT TYPE=password NAME=pa LENGTH=25 SIZE=25>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'><br>
       </FORM>");
  }
 }
if ($jommlapruefung="success") 
  {
    $_SESSION['best'] = 'gogo';
  }

if($_SESSION['best']='gogo')
{

// HERE COMES THE SCRIPT AFTER LOGIN!!
// ...
}

?>
```

This code is a couple of years old and wasn't created by me. Some details were cleared out.
Do you know how to update this script from md5 to bcrypt authentication? I thank you for any kind of helping me out! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what this script is really doing but you should rewrite it! Starting with the first query that executes sql with a POST parameter without escaping

Comment: Thanks! That part will be updated definitely!

Comment: You need to use the Joomla API to do this, that way when and if there are changes your code will still work.  Look at how the LDAP authentiction plugin works and do something similar.

Comment: Why can't you use native Joomla API to login?

Comment: Is there any documentation about authentication through Joomla! API you would recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question complety. But if you are trying to login to joomla using a form on another web site you can make a script at the root of your joomla,for example `joomlalogin.php` that looks something like this :

First part startup the joomla interface with :

```
// START: Initialize Joomla framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
// Including Required Files
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
// Create the Application
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
// END: Initialize Joomla framework
```

Then validate and login the user :

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
// Populate the data array:
$data = array();
$data['return'] = base64_decode(JRequest::getVar('return', '', 'POST', 'BASE64'));  //Page user is returned to after a successfull login
$data['username'] = JRequest::getVar('username', '', 'method', 'username');
$data['password'] = JRequest::getString('password', '', 'post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);

// Set the return URL if empty.
if (empty($data['return'])) {
    $data['return'] = 'index.php';  //If return page not set... set one.
}

// Set the return URL in the user state to allow modification by plugins
$app->setUserState('users.login.form.return', $data['return']);

// Get the log in options.
$options = array();
$options['remember'] = JRequest::getBool('remember', false);
$options['return'] = $data['return'];

// Get the log in credentials.
$credentials = array();
$credentials['username'] = $data['username'];
$credentials['password'] = $data['password'];

// Perform the log in.
if (true === $app->login($credentials, $options)) {
    // Success
    $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', array());
    $app->redirect(JRoute::_($app->getUserState('users.login.form.return'), false));
} else {
    // Login failed !
    $data['remember'] = (int)$options['remember'];
    $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
    $app->redirect('index.php', false));
}
```

I havn't tested this snipplet of code. I Just put this togetter using an existing site for you. So let me know if you encounter problemes or if i should improve / fix my answer.

You cant decrypt the password in the joomla database. but you can validate it using this method. this will create the sesssion cookie loggin the user into joomla on the same domain that your joomla is installed.